# How can I edit the text files in assets folder in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

I am using a text file in the assets folder in Android. I would like to change the data inside that text file dynamically. I am trying to open the file as follows:

```
FileOutputStream fos=this.getAssets().openNonAssetFd("data.txt").createOutputStream();
```

But it is generating the error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed`. Please help me to edit this file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Writing into `/assets` directory at runtime? AFAIK that's not possible.

You can put the original file in `/assets`, and at the first application run copy it over to the `/sdcard`.

Comment: If the file is small consider putting the initial copy into your app's private data directory instead of the sd card.

Comment: I created a new directory below res folder, and moved all HTML/JS/CSS files into that web folder.