# Remove line / string from TXT file Android c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, arrays, listview, xamarin

I am currently using a `StreamReader` to open a `.txt` file from the Assets which contains lines of strings into a `ListView`

How would I make it so that when I tap on a list view item, it deletes the line from the text File?

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ListView notesList;
    String[] notesArray;

    Stream stream;
    StreamReader streamReader;
    String line;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Hide();

        //Notes
        notesList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);

        //File name
        stream = Assets.Open("NotesData.txt");

        // Declare new List.
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
        using (streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        notesArray = lines.ToArray();

        //Load ListView Data
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, notesArray);

        notesList.Adapter = adapter;
        notesList.ItemClick += lvNotes_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void lvNotes_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Where I want the Line to be deleted!

        string toast = "Clicked: " + notesList.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking to change an asset? Or just removed the line from your `ListView`?

Comment: Change the Asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assets.Open("NotesData.txt");` I assume that you open file from the application assets. Application assets can't be modified. What you can modify is files in the file system. if you would want to do the same with the file in the file system, just remove the line with the clicked position from the `List<string> lines` when clicking on the item, and overwrite these lines into the file.

Comment: Where do I put the file, inside the File System? Which is where?

Comment: You can copy them for instance to the SD card. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845227/how-can-i-edit-the-text-files-in-assets-folder-in-android

Comment: @CodePlague, for example into your application's internal storage memory, or into SD card... Or wherever you want. The deal is that instead of using it from assets, you extract it to file system on the first launch of the app, and use it from file system after that.

Comment: Oh, I see... What directory would I put that in inside Xamarin / Visual Studio if I wanted to use the Applications Internal Memory?

Comment: @CodePlague, first you should put it into assets, as it is now. Then, when first launching the app - extract it from assets to device memory

Comment: I thought Assets extract to memory themselves... If not, how is this done? There is no documentation on it...

Comment: @CodePlague, Assets are not extracted, since they are a part of application, which is stored as APK, and is not extracted when installing. So you were able to load the file from assets into a list of lines. Now you can save this list of lines into the device memory. That will be a kind of extraction.

Comment: How would I delete a String from the `List<string> lines` and overwrite the file with the deleted String gone?

Comment: to remove item from list: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=c%23+remove+from+list to write to file: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=c%23+write+list+of+strings+to+file