# Xamarin - file:///android_asset

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

What my app does:
Load `index.html` to WebView

`index.html's Code:`

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="Posts10.html"><h2>Interesting Stuff</h2></a>
</body>
</html>
```

So whenever I click on the link, It gives me this error:

[image]

`index.html` and `Posts10.html` are located in

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"/CachedPosts"
```

a.k.a

```
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.theoctant/files/CachedPosts"
```

Comment: Is this within Forms' project or via a `Xamarin.Android` project? And what are you setting the WebView's BaseURL to be?

Comment: @SushiHangover When there is an internet connection, the WebView opens a url. But if there isn't, it opens a html file. And Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 2):

This may help. From the Xamarin docs:

> On Android, place HTML, CSS, and images in the Assets folder with
>   build action AndroidAsset as demonstrated below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=vswin#android

Comment: Can I save it programmatically in the `Assets` folder?

Comment: As @SushiHangover mentioned, I believe the Assets are compile time assets, which means you won't be able to change them during runtime. There might be a workaround, however, mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845559/119041

Comment: @SushiHangover @afilbert Then this doesn't solve my issue :/ because my program also downloads the Posts10.html programmatically :/ Is there any way for my html file to open the html file stored in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"/CachedPosts"` ??

Answer (score 0):

> When there is an internet connection, the WebView opens a url. But if there isn't, it opens a html file. And Xamarin Forms

All you need to do is swap the type of `WebViewSource` that you are using and assign the proper properties to it wether you are connected or not.

So for a Forms' WebView, if you are "Internet" connected, create a `UrlWebViewSource` and assign the property Url, but if not, create a `HtmlWebViewSource` and assign the `BaseUrl` to either  `NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath` or `file:///android_asset/` for static app bundled resources, ***or your custom cache directory***.

Something like this:

```
WebViewSource webViewSource;
if (InternetConnected)
{
    webViewSource = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = "https://stackoverflow.com" };
}
else
{
    string baseUrl = cacheDir;
    webViewSource = new HtmlWebViewSource { BaseUrl = baseUrl, Html = cachedHtml };
}
webView.Source = webViewSource;
```

Comment: OKAY the error is gone! But now when I click on the href link inside index.html to link me to Posts10, it's blank... :/

Comment: @Denise Is there any content in your cached version of `Posts10.html`?

Comment: Do you want me to post an image of my current code right now?

Comment: How are you checking the contents of cached version of `Posts10.html`?

Comment: Here as u can see 'index.html' , i just replaced it to 'Posts10.html' and it loads Posts10 and it has content inside of it.

Comment: @Denise Is the content of the html file within your cached files? i.e. Is all the content within whatever BaseUrl you are using and not split among different ones?

Comment: Yup. All of the files are inside this directory `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"/CachedPosts"` which i use as my BaseURL

Comment: @Denise If you are seeing the content of index.html but not Posts10.html what are the contents of Post10, is it valid html, etc.. and how are they both different....

Comment: Okay I just double confirmed it that it is a valid html file with <html> </html> tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174070/discussion-between-denise-and-sushihangover).